# Issue when building SonarQube On Windows 10

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

when executing the command "gradlew build" in the SonarQube project , after severals minutes i always get the error : Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
[image in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXQJe.png)
I am working with these env Windows 10 :

*Gradle 4.4
*java version "1.8.0_191" ( i have also used 1.9.2 , and 1.80_172)

Comment: I recommend to always include copy pasted text of console output, never a screenshot of it. It's searchable, indexable, less data to download on page view, and easier for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some build problems (failing tests).

To see which tests failed, look at the line "> There were failing tests. See the report at: ...". Open the shown address ("file:...html") in a browser window to see which tests are failing and why they are failing.

---

The message about "Deprecated Gradle features" is just a warning. As long as you are not the maintainer of the SonarQube project you can safely ignore it - the SonarQube project specifies exactly which version of Gradle they use.

---

If the SonarQube project decides to switch to Gradle 5.0 some time in the future, it's maintainers will need to fix all these issues.

Comment: please check the picture (updated the post) , the build failed and i coudn't find the raison behind it

Comment: @WaelDimassi I've added information on how you can find the failing tests

Comment: Thanks ! 
openning the file i've found this : 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download the plugin (test, version 1.0) from file://C:/Users/wael/AppData/Local/Temp/junit2059921731149180256/test-1.0.jar (error is : Source '\Users\wael\AppData\Local\Temp\junit2059921731149180256\test-1.0.jar' does not exist)
 at org.sonar.server.plugins.PluginDownloader.download(PluginDownloader.java:131)

Comment: @WaelDimassi Do you have checked out the project to a drive other than "C"? I also had problems building it when I checked out the project to the "D" drive. After moving it to the "C" drive I could build it successfully. This seems to be a problem specific in this SonarQube test.

Comment: I have 99% successful and failed test are : DefaultHttpDownloaderTest. openStream_network_errors

Comment: Really weird! Change it into the C: and try it too many times , same problem.
Kept trying until it did build successfully .. because fuck logic lol